# Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

see many post about the similar issue, either not very clear, or I can't understand, so post my problem here again.

I have many other 'xxxList' and 'xxxDetail', all working fine, except this always with exception:

> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name
>   "userinfo-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in
>   your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on
>   this field.

**Model**:

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    # extend Django user object
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='parkingUser')
```

**Serializer:**

```
class UserInfoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'date_joined')
```

**View:**

```
class UserInfoList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = UserInfo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserInfoSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

class UserInfoDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = UserInfo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserInfoSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )    

class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsSuperUsersGroupOrDeny)
```

**App Url:**

```
 url(r'^usersInfo/$', views.UserInfoList.as_view(), name='userInfo-list'),
 url(r'^usersInfo/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserInfoDetail.as_view(), name='userInfo-detail'),
 url(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view(), name='user-list'),
 url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserDetail.as_view(), name='user-detail'),
```

I nearly removed all logic code for testing and it can't be simpler anymore, still the same exception, the weird thing is if I tested the 'userInfoDetail' with standard url in browser like:

> http://rest.myDomain.xxx:8090/usersInfo/replaceWithIntegerNumber/

some of them return the same error, some of them return

> {
>       "detail": "Not found." }

what's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong, but the problem seems to be the capital "I" in your `usersInfo` URL. Try `name='userinfo-list'` and `name='userinfo-detail'` instead of `name='userInfo-list'` and `name='userInfo-detail'`.

Comment: can't believe this is the cause, this kind of issue always cost me hours to figure it out, thanks!